# Asterisk behind Cisco ASA 5505

Tags: cisco, nat, port-forwarding, cisco-asa

I'm in the process of upgrading from an old WRT54GL running Tomato to a Cisco ASA 5505, versioning as follows:

```
Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 9.1(5)21 
Device Manager Version 7.4(1)
```

On Tomato I had configured a simple port forward directing all traffic coming in on port 5060 to the Asterisk server's local IP address, also port 5060. I can't seem to achieve the same thing with the ASA 5505.

I have another port forward to an internal webserver that works just fine, so why does the port forward for SIP traffic not work?! I have configured them both the same way...

**Asterisk Host/NAT/Access List (this does NOT work)**

```
object network Asterisk_TCP
host 192.168.89.15
nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 5060 5060

object network Asterisk_UDP
host 192.168.89.15
nat (inside,outside) static interface service udp 5060 5060

access-list INBOUND extended permit tcp any object Asterisk_TCP eq 5060
access-list INBOUND extended permit udp any object Asterisk_UDP eq 5060
```

**Webserver Host/NAT/Access List (this DOES work!)**

```
object network Webserver
host 192.168.89.14
nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 80 80

access-list INBOUND extended permit tcp any object Webserver eq 80
```

Using [this service checking tool](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) for testing, port 80 works just fine whereas port 5060 says "Connection Refused."

I don't understand how this can be seeing as I used the exact same configuration for both requirements! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the SIP registration was failing due to the server's resolv.conf still pointing to the old DNS server (i.e., the old router).

I'm assuming those web services were failing as they were trying to connect to TCP ports, not UDP as Asterisk is configured to listen on by default.

I ended up using this hosted version of `nmap` to confirm that UDP port 5060 was open: https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/udp-port-scanner-online-nmap